# remove element(s)/numbers from list that are not within x numbers of other numbers in the list

Tags: python

mylist = [14,35,37,39,42]

I need to add together only the numbers that are within 3 numbers of each other. In other words, the numbers 35, 37, 39, and 42, but NOT the 14. Is there an easy way to check each element (number) in the list to see if there is at least one other number within 3 numbers of that number (fyi, the numbers in the list will always be in ascending order)...and then remove that number from the list so that I can then just do:

sum(mylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
>>> mylist = [14,35,37,39,42]
>>> sum(v for i, v in enumerate(mylist) 
...           if (i > 0 and v - mylist[i-1] <= 3) or 
...              (i < len(mylist) - 1 and mylist[i+1]-v <= 3))
153
```

The `i > 0` and `i < len(mylist) - 1` are so that the index never goes out of bounds and the `v - mylist[i-1] <= 3` and `mylist[i+1]-v <= 3` check if the difference to the next or previous element is less than or equal to 3.

This adds all numbers that have at least one partner that is less than or equal to 3 away if you want to group them and add different groups separately you need to alter your list a bit. For example if you have `[1, 3, 5, 20, 23, 25, 27]` it would add up all numbers.